# "clang compiler does not support -march=armv8.2-a+i8mm" during TensorFlow lite for Android selective build

Tags: tensorflow, build, android-ndk, clang, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to do a selective build of the TFLite Android runtime (in order to avoid a 100MB dependency for my app), and I'm running into a `clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=armv8.2-a+i8mm'` compiler error I can't figure out.

I followed [these instructions here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/lite_build), running build commands in the specified docker image and using all of the default settings. The build works great for x86,x86_64, and armeabi-v7a, but when I try to build arm64-v8a. I get `clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=armv8.2-a+i8mm'`.

I ran this command:

```
tf-docker /host_dir/tensorflow > bash tensorflow/lite/tools/build_aar.sh --input_models=/host_dir/glyph_classify.tflite --target_archs=arm64-v8a
```

here's the verbose error output:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/b72ef2c99f9541b6602b7fdc4f3846c6/external/XNNPACK/BUILD.bazel:3299:19: Compiling src/amalgam/gen/neoni8mm.c failed: (Exit 1): clang failed: error executing command (from target @XNNPACK//:neoni8mm_amalgam_microkernels) 
  (cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/b72ef2c99f9541b6602b7fdc4f3846c6/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=31.0.0 \
    ANDROID_NDK_API_LEVEL=21 \
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/android/ndk \
    ANDROID_SDK_API_LEVEL=23 \
    ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/android/sdk \
    CLANG_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/clang \
    DOCKER_CACHEBUSTER=1692826611111415723 \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64 \
    PATH=/root/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-6.1.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/android/sdk/platform-tools:/android/ndk \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages \
    TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 \
  external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -gcc-toolchain external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -target aarch64-none-linux-android -fpic -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android '-D__ANDROID_API__=21' -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fno-addrsig '-Werror=return-type' '-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast' '-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast' '-Werror=implicit-function-declaration' -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MF bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK/_objs/neoni8mm_amalgam_microkernels/neoni8mm.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK/_objs/neoni8mm_amalgam_microkernels/neoni8mm.pic.o' -fPIC '-DBAZEL_CURRENT_REPOSITORY="XNNPACK"' -iquote external/XNNPACK -iquote bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK -isystem external/XNNPACK/include -isystem bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK/include -isystem external/XNNPACK/src -isystem bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK/src -Wno-all -Wno-extra -Wno-deprecated -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-array-bounds -Wunused-result '-Werror=unused-result' -Wswitch '-Werror=switch' '-Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable' -DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS -Wno-gnu-offsetof-extensions -Iinclude -Isrc '-march=armv8.2-a+i8mm' '-std=c99' -O2 '--sysroot=external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64' -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/android/support/include -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include -c external/XNNPACK/src/amalgam/gen/neoni8mm.c -o bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/XNNPACK/_objs/neoni8mm_amalgam_microkernels/neoni8mm.pic.o)
# Configuration: d40643911955c7e229a325db5686958b83938e918dc0c2969bfb8d367b2f145c
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=armv8.2-a+i8mm'
Target //tmp:tensorflow-lite failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.064s, Critical Path: 0.51s
INFO: 32 processes: 30 internal, 2 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

My only guess is that since the clang compiler in question is packaged with the android ndk, maybe I need a different version of the ndk, but I am running the recommended ndk (21e). It's weird because the [Android ndk docs](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads#ndk-21e-downloads) suggest 21e has been out of support for a while now. Does Google really have products that require unsupported versions of their other products? (or maybe the doc is outdated?)

Internet search for "-march=armv8.2-a+i8mm" turns up nearly nothing helpful. Either build_aar.sh is asking for an arch that doesn't make sense, or I need to plug in a version of clang that supports that arch. In either case, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I reran the instructions from the doc again from the top and this time it worked fine. Not sure what I did wrong the first time but it must have been user error.